# Filter out users in a drop down on PCF

Tags: guidewire, gosu

In ClaimCenter I am trying to filter a drop down list to only display users that have a certain role. I am using a User input cell. There is no value range on the userinput cell only value. The value is set the user that they select so right now it's displaying all the users in the system instead of just the ones with the role that i want. Is there a way to show just the users that have the "Adjuster" role. I don't see a filter option either on this cell.

Answer (score 1):

Right click the element and select "Change Element Type"

[image]

Then select "Range Input". 
Then in the ValueRange property add a call to the code that you write. 
The code to should find the subset of users that you want to show in the drop down and return them as a List or User[], something like this might work

```
function myValueRangeFunction(pClaim: Claim) : User[] {
  //gets the group from the DB by public ID
  var adjusterGroup = Group ("cc:123");
  var adjustersOnly = new Set<User>();
  var groupUsers = adjusterGroup.MembersNoSystemUsers
  adjustersOnly.addAll(groupUsers*.Users)
  return adjustersOnly.toArray()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the input type to Range Input (or Range Cell in case you are using List View) where valueRange property calls a method which retrieves users with a specific role.

**.pcf file:**

```
<RangeInput
  editable="true"
  id="userInput"
  label="&quot;Adjusters&quot;"
  value="claim.AssignedUser"
  valueRange="UserRoleUtil_Ext.Adjusters"
  valueType="entity.User"/>
```

**UserRoleUtil_Ext.gs:**

```
uses gw.api.database.Query
uses gw.api.database.Relop

class UserRoleUtil_Ext {

  public static property get Adjusters() : User[] {
    var adjusterRole = Query.make(Role).compare(Role#Name, Relop.Equals, "Adjuster").select().AtMostOneRow
    // Alternatively, you can retrieve the Role by its public-id, e.g.:
    // var roleRetrievedById = Query.make(Role).compare(Role#PublicID, Relop.Equals, "cc:1").select().AtMostOneRow
    return adjusterRole.AllUsersArray
  }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i have to default a particular queueName in a toolbar filter with respect to logged in user. if user belongs to any of these groups it should default to "Underwriting queue" else it should show "ALL Open" as default value.